# Are SystemGroups same in all kernel versions/Linux distributions or not?

Tags: linux

A was looking for description of SystemGroups in CentOS 8 but was able to find this for Debian only:

https://wiki.debian.org/SystemGroups

This has led me to the question:

Are SystemGroups same in all kernel versions/Linux distributions or not?
Are these depending on kernel itself or something else?

If you find that this question doesn't belong here, please let me know where should I put it and I'll delete this one.

Answer (score 1):

> Are SystemGroups same in all kernel versions/Linux distributions or not?

No, they may even differ between different versions of the same distro.

Comment: Thank you for clarification!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about them. They are just groups.

Someone has defined a group. They have then created some files that are readable/writable by this group, or created a fire-wall / sudo / … rule that uses this group.

Comment: Thank you for this answer also, it is clear now how this works, I was in an illusion that these are something special.